# Turn on eclipse syntax highlighting for scripts besides JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, paperjs

When you're editing an html file in Eclipse with Web Developer Tools, Eclipse knows that anything inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag is JavaScript, and turns on the appropriate helpers, such as syntax highlighting.

However, I want to have the SAME help when editing text inside a tag like this:

```
<script type="text/paperscript">
```

Where can I tell Eclipse to recognize text inside this tag as JavaScript?

Comment: Similar question, in which the asker just put the paperscript in a separate .js file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015609/syntax-highlighting-for-paperscript-paperjs-on-aptana-studio-3